# In LaTeX, how does one get a colon instead of a full stop after a theorem?

Tags: latex, definition

I want to know if there is some way to change that full stop after **Definition.** to a colon, i.e. to get **Definition:** (and for the other environments in the "definition" theoremstyle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach may be to define yourself a [new style](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Theorem_styles):

> \newtheoremstyle{stylename} % name of the style to be used
>
> {spaceabove}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
>
> {spacebelow}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
>
> {bodyfont}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
>
> {indent}% measure of space to indent
>
> {headfont}% name of head font
>
> {headpunctuation}% punctuation between head and body
>
> {headspace}% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
>
> {headspec}% Manually specify head

In this case, you would copy the existing definition style, and then change the value of `headpunctuation`.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've sorted it out now.

Answer (score 1):

AMS LaTeX should be included in any modern distribution. It (or the [`amsthm`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=amsthm) standalone package ([docs here [PDF link!](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/classes/amsthdoc.pdf))) provides the `\theoremstyle` and `\newtheoremstyle` commands.